# What determines sort order in Collections.sort where List contains non-alphanumeric characters?

Tags: java, sorting

I have code that sorts an ArrayList of elements based on one attribute called 'title' which is of type String. The code uses Collator like this:

```
Collator( Collator collator = Collator.getInstance(); ).
```

I have two objects with title "@a" and the other object has title "#a"

I pass these objects as a List and call

```
Collections.sort(list,comparator)
```

This gives the order as

```
"@a" "#a"
```

Why is "#a" appearing last even though its ASCII value is less than "@a" ?

Comment: Can you show us your code? There may be an issue there...

Comment: Please create an SSCCE; That's not what I observe. You must have some other character in your title (a space, or something like that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> #### Why is # appearing last even though its ASCII value is less than @ ?

My clean-room implementation:

```
final List<String> list = Arrays.asList("@a", "#a");
Collections.sort(list);
System.out.println(list);
```

Output:

> [#a, @a]

This code doesn't reproduce your problem.

For reference: 
'#' is 0x23 
'@' is 0x40

Everything looks normal.

---

EDIT: new code following your comment *"The code uses Collator but its used as `Collator collator = Collator.getInstance();` not specific to any locale."*:

```
final List<String> list = Arrays.asList("@a", "#a");
final Collator c = Collator.getInstance();

Collections.sort(list, c);
System.out.println(list);
```

Output:

> [@a, #a]

**This reproduces your problem.**

If I use `Collator.getInstance()` to sort the ASCII table, this is the output I get:

> -, _, ,, ;, :, !, ?, /, ., `, ^, ', ", (, ), [, ], {, }, @, $, *, \, &, #, %, +, <, =, >, |, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, a, A, b, B, c, C, d, D, e, E, f, F, g, G, h, H, i, I, j, J, k, K, l, L, m, M, n, N, o, O, p, P, q, Q, r, R, s, S, t, T, u, U, v, V, w, W, x, X, y, Y, z, Z

You can see this is quite different from the ASCII collating order:

> ", #, $, %, &, ', (, ), *, +, ,, -, ., /, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, :, ;, <, =, >, ?, @, A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X, Y, Z, [, \, ], ^, _, `, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z, {, |, }

For OP's interest, this is the code used to create this output:

```
final List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
final Collator col = Collator.getInstance();

for (char c = '!'; c < '~'; c++)
{
  list.add(c+"");
}

Collections.sort(list, col);
System.out.println(list);
```

Comment: The code uses Collator but its used as Collator collator = Collator.getInstance(); not specific to any locale.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more detailed? I am not getting what do you mean by "sort the ASCII table" and "ASCII collating order"

Comment: @user1225543: the ASCII collating order is the order that you were originally expecting (based on ASCII values).  By "sort the ASCII table", I meant I build a list of the printable ASCII characters (0x21 through 0x7E), then sorted them using the `Collator.getInstance()`.  See edited answer for the code I'm referring to.

Comment: Thank you very much the good clean explanation. Now I got the point.

Answer (score 4):

Based on one of your comments, you're using a collator to sort your titles. Why you didn't say that in your question is beyond me.

Anyway, the collator sorts Strings according to locale preferences. It doesn't sort in lexicographic order. And the collator you're using considers that the right order is the one you observe. If you want lexicographical order, you should not use a collator.

Also note that a collator is always associated to a locale. The javadoc of `Collator.getInstance()` method says:

> Gets the Collator for the current default locale.

Answer (score 2):

No, the output is "#a","@a". Which is absolutely right.

Answer (score 0):

You normally provide a Comparator when you want the order to be different to normal.

```
List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
words.add("#a");
words.add("@a");
Collections.sort(words);
System.out.println("Natural order: " + words);

Collections.sort(words, Collections.reverseOrder());
System.out.println("Reverse natural order: " + words);
```

prints

```
Natural order: [#a, @a]
Reverse natural order: [@a, #a]
```

So if the order is the reverse of ASCII, its because that what you defined in your Comparator to be the order (whether you are aware that you did this or not)

Comment: This is on the same topic.  Collections.sort() is sorting on ASCII for me but the column of data I am verifying is sorted is somehow different.  Excel sorts the same way as the table is sorted (ascii).  My Collections.sort() needs a collator but I don't know which.  Can you help?  Here is the order that it should sort (I can get part of it by comparing ignore case but that does not work for special characters).:

`' - # $ % & ( ) * , . / : ; ? @ [ \ ] ^ _ ` { | } + < = > 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A a B b C c D d E e F f G g H h I i J j K k L l M m N n O o P p Q q R r S s T t U u V v W w X x Y y Z z`

Comment: Sorry, a backtick is in there but the editing thinks it is a control character